# Can you set variables as a column name?

Tags: r, dataframe, header, names

If I have a dataframe as follows, with a combination of text values and NA cells:

| id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | NA | NA | sample | NA | weight | etc |
| id2 | NA | size | NA | NA | NA | etc |
| id3 | volume | size | sample | NA | NA | etc |
| id4 | NA | NA | NA | qty | NA | etc |
| id5 | NA | NA | sample | qty | weight | etc |

Is it possible to rename the header with the most frequently used value in that column, as follows?

| id | volume | size | sample | qty | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | NA | NA | sample | NA | weight |
| id2 | NA | size | NA | NA | NA |
| id3 | volume | size | sample | NA | NA |
| id4 | NA | NA | NA | qty | NA |
| id5 | NA | NA | sample | qty | weight |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

```
> cbind(df[1], setNames(df[-1], sapply(df[-1], function(x) unique(na.omit(x)))))
   id volume size sample  qty weight
1 id1   <NA> <NA> sample <NA> weight
2 id2   <NA> size   <NA> <NA>   <NA>
3 id3 volume size sample <NA>   <NA>
4 id4   <NA> <NA>   <NA>  qty   <NA>
5 id5   <NA> <NA> sample  qty weight
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"), Col1 = c(NA,
NA, "volume", NA, NA), Col2 = c(NA, "size", "size", NA, NA),
    Col3 = c("sample", NA, "sample", NA, "sample"), Col4 = c(NA,
    NA, NA, "qty", "qty"), Col5 = c("weight", NA, NA, NA, "weight"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the most frequent value in each column using `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/3962914).

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(na.omit(x))
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Apply it for each column and change the column name.

```
names(df)[-1] <- sapply(df[-1], Mode)
df

#   id volume size sample  qty weight
#1 id1   <NA> <NA> sample <NA> weight
#2 id2   <NA> size   <NA> <NA>   <NA>
#3 id3 volume size sample <NA>   <NA>
#4 id4   <NA> <NA>   <NA>  qty   <NA>
#5 id5   <NA> <NA> sample  qty weight
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that there was a mode function that could handle text- I thought that it would only work on integers.